# Finding the value of a 100 digit number mod 10^9+7 in C

Tags: c++, numbers, modulo

Say I'm given 100 digit number (input can be string) . I want to find the value of that number % mod  , where mod is 10^9+7. How can I go about getting the answer. I have already implemented the addition and subtraction functions on large numbers using string manipulation.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How about implementing division next? :)

Comment: As i said , I have only done addition and subtraction on strings. I tried all data types but get runtime error when I try to find very large numbers % mod such as 10^100

Comment: 10 bucks says this is a Project Euler of some sort and that you don't actually need to compute that 100 digit number to begin with.

Comment: Could you give me a hint. I don't have an idea to start

Comment: There should be a C++ library with arbitrary-length integers. Unless you're only doing it once (or doing it as a challenge), using string manipulation for large-integer arithmetic seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @AnirudhRaja If you show the signatures of your addition and subtraction, things may go a little better: at least we'll have a better idea of the interfaces that you are building.

Comment: @Steve Jessop : So, I should perform division of the two numbers and then possibly get the remainder , is it ?

Comment: @SteveJessop One can skip multiplication and go straight to long division in binary, or even in decimal by repeatedly adding a number to itself for two to nine times :)

Comment: Is there any mathematical hint , like some  sort of pattern repetition or something

Comment: @AnirudhRaja There's no pattern, because `10^9+7` is a prime number (in fact, it's the first prime with ten digits).

Comment: Ok, so the only way is using strings ?

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha, lol.

Comment: This can be done with a single O(N) time pass over the entire string. Here's a hint: Use [Horner's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) combined with intermediate modular reductions.

Comment: How did you get to the 100 digit number to begin with?

Comment: Use the [Grid method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_method_multiplication) to implement multiplication.

Comment: @FredOverflow  : Its actually a part of a problem which requires this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10<sup>9</sup> is -7 modulo 1000000007.

Break the 100 digit number `N` into blocks of 9 digits (a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ...) starting from the right. We have:

```
N = a0 + a1*10^9 + a2*10^18 + ...
```

The modulus is a<sub>0</sub> - 7*a<sub>1</sub> + 49*a<sub>2</sub> - ...

For example, suppose you are to calculate 87564875326485487234854862386245865486238654862 modulo 1000000007. You break this string of digits into blocks of 9 starting from the right:

- a<sub>0</sub> = 238654862
- a<sub>1</sub> = 245865486
- a<sub>2</sub> = 245865486
- a<sub>3</sub> = 854862386
- a<sub>4</sub> = 485487234
- a<sub>5</sub> = 564875326
- a<sub>6</sub> = 87

Now you convert each block into an integer and calculate m = a<sub>0</sub> - 7*a<sub>1</sub> + 49*a<sub>2</sub> - 323*a<sub>3</sub> +... (hint: use 64 bit integers).

Now `N = m (mod 1000000007)`.

Comment: This is in fact the correct answer. Even a bit more optimized than the one I had in mind.

Comment: So, basically calculation of a0 is the imp one . ?

Comment: ok, but I can't accept such a huge number in C++ , so I take it in as a string. Then how to proceed

Comment: a0 is the number that consists of the 9 right most digits, a1 is the following 9, and so on.

Comment: @Joni could you please help me out . How to convert the string into the value I require

Comment: Are you asking how to break a string into blocks of 9 characters, or how to convert a string of 9 digits into an integer?

Comment: Yes, as I can't input a large number as an integer. I'll take it as a string . Then how to use the formula you have suggested for the set of characters in a string

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: @Joni , Thanks a ton ! Brilliant explanation .