# Remainder of a very very large number using a prime number

Tags: algorithm, math

I am stuck with a problem where I need to find remainder of a very large number using a prime number. Actual problem is that the number is quite large, around `10^100`. So we can not store it in any variable and only option is to store it in an array.

Now we need to find remainder of this number using a prime number say `(10^9)+7`.

I can't think of any idea, any suggestions?

P.S.: Programming language is C++.

Comment: You can use a `BigInteger` in .Net 4.0 rather than an array, you would probably get a better response to this question over at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, but how will remainder operation will work on it. And more CPU cycles will be wasted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the value of a 100 digit number mod 10^9+7 in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163085/finding-the-value-of-a-100-digit-number-mod-1097-in-c)

Comment: An array of digits? The obvious approach is to do it the way you'd do it on paper.

Answer (score 2):

What programming language? C/C++, Java, PHP, Perl, JavaScript... all have some form of Big Integer that allows you to have integers up to the maximum length of a null-terminated string. The actual syntax depends on the language, but would be something like:

```
$num = new BigInt("1234567891234567912346579865432165498765462132165498765431");
$prime = new BigInt("54657613216846346874321638743");
$mod = $num.mod($prime);
```

Comment: You will find more classes than you want by searching for "c++ bigint class". If I remember correctly, making a bigint class was one of the tasks in The Art of Computer Programming.

Answer (score 2):

In general I would exploit the fact that

```
a^n mod b == (a mod b)^n mod b
```

So in this example, you might calculate

```
= 10^100 mod 10^9 + 7 = (10^10 mod 10^9 + 7)^10  mod 10^9 + 7

= (999999937) ^ 10 mod 10^9 + 7
= ((999999937) ^ 2 mod 10^9 + 7) ^ 5 mod 10^9 + 7
= 4900 ^ 5 mod 10^9 +7
= 226732710
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

A decimal number (e.g. 1234) can be built from its digits in the following way:

```
x=1;
x=x*10+2;
x=x*10+3;
x=x*10+4;//x=1234
```

(you start from the most significant digit and take next one every time).

Since addition and multiplication allow to move modulus operation into them, you can simply apply modulus (e.g. 7) on every step:

```
x=1;
x=(x*10+2)%7;
x=(x*10+3)%7;
x=(x*10+4)%7;//x=1234%7
```

If your prime is around 10^9, 32-bit integers will not be sufficient, but 64-bit will be more than enough.